# Any way to stop Xcode from generating folders like this?

Tags: xcode, filenames, spaces, gmp

I was trying to build GMP on OS X, and it fails with the following error:

```
/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup: No such file or directory
```

The problem is due to this command:

```
/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/SMSandboxTools-tmp/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
```

Someone isn't parsing the directory name properly. Does anyone know how to prevent Xcode from generating folders with spaces in the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My installation **was** botched. (`Cleanup at Startup` sounds an awful lot like something the OS leaves around for dealing with after an update... and I did have an update with issues.) I'm guessing Apple's developers have encountered this before, as the Xcode manual for the command line tools has the following:

> The Command Line Developer tools package has been updated to include `xcrun`. `xcrun` adds support for the following:
>   1. The `--show-sdk-path` option queries SDK paths

Invoking `xcrun --show-sdk-path` gave the nasty, ugly path with `Cleanup at Startup`. On the same help page is this:

> On OS X Mavericks, `xcode-select` provides the `--reset` flag to revert to using the default search paths.

I invoked `xcode-select --reset`, and that fixed my problem! GMP built smoothly, and `xcrun --show-sdk-path` now displays nothing... which seems weird, except that, as I say, gmp ran, tested 100% correct, and installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent `Clean at Startup` from being generated.

Your build script could either escape the spaces, or simply put the whole path in quotes. For example, this doesn't work:

```
$ cd /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup
```

But this does:

```
$ cd "/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup"
```

If you don't want to fix the script yourself, I would just [open an issue with the GMP developers](https://gmplib.org/manual/Reporting-Bugs.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to think that there was an error in my Xcode installation. Are you saying this is normal, rather than putting `/usr/bin/make` in that string?

Comment: @JohnPerry It's normal for directories to have spaces in them. Build scripts should expect directories with spaces, but often they don't, especially on cross-platform projects.

Comment: Read my answer below: OSX was supplying the wrong directory. Once I found a way to fix it, it worked out.